# Unsetting variable doesn't work

Tags: bash, function, unset

I want to parse if the user input is an **integer**, and force him to do so. First time (`iquant`) running `chkip()` works, second time (`idays`), I immediately get: "Error: Not a number. Please retry." New input works then. I am unsetting `ipn` before `break`, so what's the deal?

```
chkip()
{
    ipn=$1
    while true;
    do
        if [[ "$ipn" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then 
            unset ipn
            break
        else 
            echo "Error: Not a number. Please retry"
            read ipn
        fi
    done
}

echo "Please enter the name of the Set:"
read ap
echo "How much keys do you want to create [NUMBER]:"
read iquant
chkip $iquant 
echo "How often do you want to change the Keys? [DAYS] ?:"
read idays
chkip $idayz
```

Comment: You probably want to quote those expansions (`"$1"`, `"$iquant"`, etc), and consider `set -u` to get an error when you try to use an unset variable.

Comment: Maybe you should also add a return value, because after the correction `iquant` will contain the old value and `ipn` will be out of scope.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! +1 for including complete, self-contained source code, expected result and actual result. This makes the question clear, unambiguous and easy to answer and verify.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're reading "iday**s**" but passing "iday**z**" instead of the former.

```
read idays
chkip $idayz
```

Change **$idayz** to **$idays** and you'll be on your way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bigger problem: your function only modifies the variable named `ipn`, not whatever variable whose *value* you pass as an argument.

This function takes the *name* of a variable, and uses indirect parameter expansion to check the value of that variable. The *value* of `var` is passed to `read` as the name of the variable to populate.

```
chkip () {
  local var=$1
  until [[ ${!var} =~ ^[[:digit:]]$ ]]; then
    read -p "Error: Not a number. Please retry: " "$var"
  done
}
```

Here, the *name*, not the value, of the variable is passed as the argument to `chkip`.

```
read -p "Please enter the name of the set: " ap
read -p "How many keys do you want to create? [NUMBER]: " iquant
chkip iquant 
read -p "How often do you want to change the keys? [DAYS]: " idays
chkip idays
```